# ExtJS 5.0 cellclick event returns incorrect column

Tags: events, extjs, datagridcolumn

I'm trying to use cellclick on a grid where based on a certain column clicked, I want to  run some operations. But every time, it returns a wrong column i.e. if I click on column 0 (first col), it returns the next column.

```
cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ){
    console.info(view.getGridColumns()[cellIndex].dataIndex);
if(view.getGridColumns()[cellIndex].dataIndex === 'someCol'){
//do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, ExtJS 5, in the cellclick event the cellIndex returns an Index considering the columns start at 1, 2, 3... but the column Index is starting at 0,1,2,3.
I have added a workaround to use CellIndex-1 for now to get my code to work

Comment: Do you have a rowexpander or a hidden column in your grid?

Comment: I do have one hidden column which I use for groupBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view.getGridColumns() only returns visible columns. Instead I changed it to, the following and this returns all the visible/hidden columns.

```
Ext.getCmp('gridId').columns[cellIndex].dataIndex
```

Thank you @Yellen for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when one of the columns are hidden cellIndex exceeds the visible number of columns.

Alternatively, I used

```
        if(view.getColumnManager().columns[cellIndex].dataIndex.toLowerCase() == 'yourdataindex') {
```

// do something

}